# Proto-Slavic a-stem locative plural in -asъ?

Tags: historical-linguistics, morphology, slavic-languages, nominals

Browsing through Wiktionary, I ran across a note in a-stem declension tables (like [žena](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/%C5%BEena)) which claims that *-asъ* is the expected Balto-Slavic form of locative plural, which is however found only in some Old Czech documents and is replaced elsewhere by *-axъ* in analogy with the other declension types. I've never seen this claim in literature, Czech or any other, and it does not seem to be substantiated on Wiktionary, so I was wondering if anybody here might have some pointers on this.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the use of x in -axъ is thought to be related to the "[ruki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Balto-Slavic_language#RUKI_law)" law. However, becasue this is not the usual context for the application of this sound law, it is supposed that some kind of analogy caused the original *s sound to develop to [x] in this ending. As Atamiri's answer mentions, some evidence that the locative plural originally had the consonant *s comes from Baltic languages like Lithuanian.

According to "[On The Origins Of *x* in Slavic](https://digilib.phil.muni.cz/bitstream/handle/11222.digilib/127154/1_LinguisticaBrunensia_14-2013-1_10.pdf?sequence=1)", by Ondřej Šefčík, in *Linguistica Brunensia* 61, 2013:

> We can formulate Pedersen’s Law for Common Slavic as:
>   “If Indo-European **s* is preceded by **ı̄̆, ū̆, r, k* and is not followed by an obstruent, it changes to **š*, if followed by a palatal/front phoneme, or to **x*, if followed by a non-palatal/back phoneme.”

(122)

> The collateral effect of Pedersen’s Law and the source of a **secondary analogical *x*** is the *x* of the Slavic sigmatic aorist when, besides regular forms like OCS *rěxъ, prosixъ, krychъ,* there arose by analogy such new forms as *znaxъ* and *nesoxъ.* The original forms that do not show the effect of Pedersen’s Law are attested in OCS *bljusъ, grěsъ.* Similarly, the **locative plural** OCS *ženachъ* is due to analogy with the regular *synъxъ.*

(p. 123)

Sorry, I don't know anything about possible attested examples of -asъ, but I hope this explains why it might be considered the "expected" form.

Answer (score 2):

-asъ changed to -axъ in this context, it’s a pretty known fact in historical Slavonic linguistics. Note that -s- can still be found in modern Lithuanian in plural locatives.

Comment: In modern Slovenian, and archaic Croatian '-ah' is common: "na planincah" (on the mountains).